# How to avoid retrieving literal content of PHP script when debugging?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am developing an HTML/Javascript/JQuery page retrieving a JSON returned by a PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
url: "data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
success: function(rate) {
        var retr = JSON.stringify(rate, null, 2);
        $("#data").text(retr);
},
    error: function(request,error) {
        alert(request.statusText);
    }
});
```

When I view the HTML page from my local PC, the Ajax returns the PHP script code rather than the JSON the PHP code should generate. Somehow, it makes sense since it does not go through a PHP engine.

I have tried replacing `url: "data.php"` with `url: "http://www.mysite.com/data.php"` or `url: "www.mysite.com/data.php"`, but it does not work.

I would like to avoid uploading my page on a server to test it. I would like to be able to invoke the PHP on my PHP server directly from my local PC. Is this possible?

Comment: May be your web server is not running.

Comment: make sure your PHP is enclosed in `<?php ?>`

Comment: Is your script between `<?PHP` and `?>`?

Comment: have you installed php and a webserver on your local machine?

Comment: If I call http://www.mysite.com/data.php directly from my browser, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to upload the page on the server, otherwise you will be restricted by [**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

add the following line in your php script

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo json_encode("hello");
?>
```

Comment: Any chance I can work around CORS, just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post would help you solve your issue just go through the steps mentioned here.

http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/shows_code.htm

Answer (score 0):

Take care if the php file has properly set php tag